# How to include material icon library in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

(I refer this link [Issue #2662](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2662) for that), I add CSS in `angular.json` and `import library instyle.css` It gives an error like :

```
./src/styles.css (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/styles.css)
```

What is the proper way to install material icon library in the local project in angular?

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

`angular.json`

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
],
```

`style.css`

```
@import "~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons";
```

`index.html`

```
<link href="../material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/fonts/" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: might be related to path issue. "styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
],

Comment: did you trying importing the css file in index.html using link tag?

Comment: please try and let me know

Comment: Did you include `MatIconModule` in imports of your Module?

Comment: You need to load css file right? <link href="../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">. Try this code

Comment: have you tried to import it into your style file like this: `@import "~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

using this link resolved my problem(https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons)

```
npm i material-icons
```

styles.css

```
@import '~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

Comment: If you want to host the icons locally inside the Angular project, here is a good post https://thecodeframework.com/host-google-material-icon-fonts-locally-in-angular-in-5-simple-steps/

Answer (score 10):

First install via npm the material-icon package:

```
npm install material-icons --save
```

Then import the CSS library on your Angular project editing the angular.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"
]
```

Comment: For me, this is the best way to declare the file. Thanks for the information.

Comment: for me:
"node_modules/material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
not
"node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",

Comment: Some version path is not same as previous version. You might check the path in node_modules after installed in project.

Answer (score 1):

**styles.css**

```
mat-icon {
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my experience in solving this. Actually I used `!important` for my fonts at some stage and later realized my icons were not working. Once removing important my issue was resolved and it started working again.

NOTE: Don't use `!important` unless really necessary and you know what you are doing

Answer (score -1):

Try to post this code in your **index.html** :

```js
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

Comment: I am downvoting every answer pointing to https://fonts.googleapis.com because the OP is interesting at **embedding** the fonts into the project. Some people run behind firewalls that don't like external content. E.g. banks