# Remove webfont.js as render-blocking resource - lighthouse

Tags: javascript, html, angular, lighthouse, webfont-loader

I'm currently trying to optimize my site and load font family asynchronously

At first it was an issue with material icons like in image below

[image]

After getting rid of this issue by using webfontloader in index.html I now have this error, which hasn't been as easy to get rid of

[image]

To try and solve it I changed the CDN link `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>` to webfont.js to using `npm i webfontloader` and loading it locally, but the issue is still there. How can I get webfont.js to not be render-blocking?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/logo.ico">


  <script src="../node_modules/webfontloader/src/core/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ['Material+Icons']
      }
    });
  </script>



</head>

<body>
  <app-root>

  </app-root>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn’t use a js to do this, and if I had to I would move the script to the footer of the html. Why not simply go for an @font-face load in your css..?

Comment: TBH, I've never used ```@font-face```. If you say I can use ```@font-face``` and it would be non-blocking to help the page load faster than I'm not opposed to it. Would you be able to provide an example of adding material icons using ```@font-face``` to angular? I found this answer, but it doesn't use font-face so maybe it's not the same thing? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537475/4350389

Comment: The import in the link you gave can also work. For @font-face (always my pref), check this: https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website